# Android Volley: Sending many request caused app to close

Tags: android, android-volley

(Warning) I'm pretty new to Android programming, what I did might look silly, so please pardon me.

I am writing an app to upload my Contact Book on my Android phone to a MySQL server using Volley.

I have total of 32 entries and if I send them all, the app will close with message "[App Name] has stopped, Open app again"

If I set the limit lower, like 15, no error triggered, but I'd have got only 7 or 8 rows recorded in my data table, not 15. This is not good.

```
private fun saveContact()
{
    val guid: String = "User1999" //just some value
    var contact: String
    var stringRequest: StringRequest
    var result: String

    // adapter is an ArrayAdapter<String> I used to hold the items, and put in a Spinner for view
    // it is defined as global variable
    for(index in 0..adapter.count)
    {
        contact = adapter.getItem(index).toString()
        stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
        Method.POST, "http://192.168.1.109/saveContact.php",
        Response.Listener { response ->
            try
            {
                val obj = JSONObject(response)
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    result = obj.getString("result")
                    if (result != "PASS")
                    { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fail: $result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                }
                else { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error: null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
            }
            catch (e: JSONException)
            { e.printStackTrace() }
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { volleyError -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, 
        volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
        {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>
            {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params["guid"] = guid
                params["contact"] = contact
                return params
            }
        }
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
    //intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
    //startActivity(intent)
}
```

I know, running a for-loop here isn't really a good idea, but I'm totally new so I can only use something I'm familiar with (C++) as a reference for what to do.

The PHP part has been thoroughly tested, no problem there. I guess the error comes from too many response from the many StringRequest I send.

Can anyone suggest what is the right way to do multiple request (potentially quite a big number, like 2 or 3 hundreds), or how to sent the contact book data (consists of 2 fields: a User ID or, Owner ID, and Phone number) in one chunk? I know of some people who could have hundreds of contacts, if my app can't handle 32 entries properly, it'd be useless for more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you include the stack trace of the error you described!

Comment: Do you mean the Run tab output?

Comment: Thanks to you, Henry, I spotted the error in the Run Log, it's overflowed with messages so I didn't spot it before. It's index out of bound.

Comment: @KwChoy so, did you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below. I really hope Android Studio would pop a message about error (like any other IDE) instead of just keeping quiet and hoping everyone will know there is error information waiting to be discovered in the Run Log tab.

Answer (score 0):

the crash was due to index out of bound. The problem went away when I changed the for-loop to:

```
for(index in 0 until adapter.count)
```

instead of

```
for(index in 0..adapter.count)
```

Kotlin is a very weird language...